# ¿Cómo hacer una copia de va_list con la opción -ansi activada?

Tags: c, gcc

La función va_copy no funciona si `-ansi` está activada y
hacer algo como `destino = origen` produce el siguiente error en gcc:

**error: assignment to expression with array type**

Entonces, ¿cómo se hace?

---

```cpp
va_list destino, origen;

va_start(origen, formato);

destino = origen; /*error: assignment to expression with array type*/

va_end(destino);
va_end(origen);
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Sin ver el código es difícil ayudarte.

Comment: @Mateo: No sé como te puede servir, pero ahí tienes.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que estas agregando un arreglo sobre otro arreglo, intenta de esta manera

```
va_list destino, origen;
va_start(origen, formato);
va_copy(destino, origen);
va_end(origen);
va_end(destino);
```

Para copiar una lista de argumentos variables a otra, utiliza la función va_copy() de la biblioteca stdarg.h

Saludos,